# Extra white space when saving figure

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library

When saving an Image with python I get an extra pixel column on the right and an extra pixel line on the bottom. I need to fix this. Is it possible that savefig() is not considering pixels number 0 when saving the figure?

```
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l=1000;

fig = plt.figure(frameon = False)
fig.set_size_inches(1, 1)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0, 0, 1, 1],)
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
circ=plt.Circle((0.5,0.5),0.5,color='gray',)        
fig.gca().add_artist(circ)      
circ.set_fill('gray')
circ.set_edgecolor('black')
circ.set_linewidth(0.2)
circ.set_antialiased(False)
fig.savefig('img.png', dpi=l)
Image.open('img.png').convert('L').save('img.png')
```

Comment: your example is working fine here. There's no extra line.

Comment: I still can't get this solved. Can anyone help me?

Comment: could it be because of my python version? Python 2.7.3, I'm using debian stable...